# Show remote content in modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am facing one issue that is failed to show remote content to modal dialog (bootstrap).
Is it possible to append response content to modal content ?

**Sample of index.jsp**

```
 <form id="cusPayment" name="cusPayment" method="post" action="CusConfirmPayment.jsp" >   
     <input id="lflag" name="lflag" type="hidden" value="E">

     <a data-toggle="modal"   data-remote="CusConfirmPayment.jsp" href="#"  data-target="#myModal" id='paynow322' class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Load External Page</a>  

 </form> 

    <!-- Modal --> //show the remote content
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" class="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
        </div> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {      

             $('a#paynow322').click(function(){

                var form  = $("#cusPayment");
                var $modal = $('#myModal');

             $.ajax({

                 type: form.attr('method'),  //post method
                 url: form.attr('action'), //ajaxformexample url
                 data: form.serialize(), // serialize input data values
                 success: function (data) {

                 var result=data; //response content html 

                 $('#myModal').modal({
                      show:true
                 });
```

Comment: Don't use the `data-remote`/`remote` option, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .Is it possible to append response content to modal conten ?

Yes it is possible.

try this code on your success cal back.

```
success: function (data) {
               var result=data; //response content html 
                $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').html(result);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
```

This will update modal contents and show your modal.

[docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: hi , #arun , thank for your answer . But after i try it ,inside modal-content still empty .

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like $('#modal-content').innerHTML = result ?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (data) {
               var result=data; //response content html 
                $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').html(result);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
```

i try this and its it worked